# How can I make sure to wait for EWS to return my OAuth Token before using it? And how do I efficiently refresh it?

Tags: vb.net, async-await, oauth, exchangewebservices

I have a older email forwarding app that takes email once a minute, compares the from address to a user inputted list, and then forwards the email based on a schedule.  It has been using Basic Authentication through the Microsoft EWS add-in.  With the phasing out of that auth method I've been working on using OAuth through Microsofts tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth .

So far I have been able to do most everything and I can get my program working but with a couple weird work-arounds that I assume mean I'm doing something wrong.  First I have this function to get my token:

```
Private Async Function RefreshToken() As Threading.Tasks.Task
    Dim cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("myAppID").WithClientSecret("mySecret").WithTenantId("myTenantID").Build()
    Dim ewsScopes = New String() {"https://outlook.office365.com/.default"}
    Try
        MyRefreshTimer.Stop()
        Dim authResult = Await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync()
        myToken = authResult.AccessToken
        MyRefreshTimer.Interval = CInt((authResult.ExpiresOn - Date.Now.ToUniversalTime).TotalMilliseconds)
        MyRefreshTimer.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

I have a timer so I can refresh the token based on it's expiration, the timer function simply calls whats above.  I then have a function that returns a new instance of the client so I can use it when needed:

```
Friend Function GetEWSClient() As ExchangeService
    Try
        Dim myEWSClient As New ExchangeService With {
            .Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
            .Credentials = New OAuthCredentials(myToken),
            .ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, My.Settings.EmailAddress)
        }
        myEWSClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", My.Settings.EmailAddress)
        Return myEWSClient
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

This is called like:

```
Dim newMsg As New EmailMessage(GetEWSClient)
```

And works great.  The problem I'm having is on startup sometimes the token isn't retrieved before the program goes to do something with the client and I'm assuming it's because it's called asynchronously.  So if I call `RefreshToken()` and immediately try to get a client with `GetEWSClient` it will fail due to having a empty token.

So I have two questions.  First what is the best way to deal with this or wait for the token to get returned before calling anything else?  For now I've put in a hack which kind of manually refreshes the token and returns a client all in one function.  I call this at the beginning of my program and if it returns a client I have a connection and if not something is wrong.  It's just a combination of the two above but it works:

```
Friend Async Function SetupExchangeConnection() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ExchangeService) ' Gets the initial connection working
    Dim cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("myAppID").WithClientSecret("mySecret").WithTenantId("myTenantID").Build()
    Dim ewsScopes = New String() {"https://outlook.office365.com/.default"}
    Try
        Dim authResult = Await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync()
        Dim myExchangeService As New ExchangeService With {
        .Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
    }
        Dim ewsClient = New ExchangeService With {
                .Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
                .Credentials = New OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
                .ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, My.Settings.EmailAddress)
            }
        ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", My.Settings.EmailAddress)
        Return ewsClient
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

I don't want to call sleep statements but I was thinking of adding something that says if `myToken` is blank then sleep for 1 second and recheck and just do this for x seconds until the function returns a token but I really try to avoid sleep statements and I assume this problem has already been solved but I can't find the answer.

Second is having a timer the best way to refresh the token or should I look for a 401 unauthorized, refresh the token, and try again?  I would think proactively trying to refresh would make the most sense but again I'm new to this and want to do things the proper way if possible.

**EDIT**:  Based on the comments I have tried to simplify this and it is now a single function that seems to work.  Maybe I was just over-complicating it:

```
Friend Async Function GetEWSClient() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ExchangeService)
    Dim cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("AppId").WithClientSecret("Secret").WithTenantId("TenantID").Build()
    Dim ewsScopes = New String() {"https://outlook.office365.com/.default"}
    Try
        Dim authResult = Await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync()
        Dim myEWSClient As New ExchangeService With {
            .Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
            .Credentials = New OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
            .ImpersonatedUserId = New ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, My.Settings.EmailAddress)
        }
        myEWSClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", My.Settings.EmailAddress)
        Return myEWSClient
    Catch ex As MsalClientException
        Debug.WriteLine("Error acquiring access token.  Details: " & ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Error getting EWSClient.  Details: " & ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

And then I'm calling it with `GetEWSClient.Result` and so far so good.

Comment: You say "I assume this problem has already been solved," and I would say that the way it has been solved is you can `Await` the token.  Which is what you're already doing, but in another workflow.  Once you do that, you're inherently trying to set up some additional polling or notification scheme, and it will necessarily be somewhat complicated.

Comment: Polling is probably the easiest thing to set up.  You can `Await Task.Delay(x)` instead of `Sleep(x)`, and it's probably preferable to do if you're on the UI thread so that your UI remains responsive.  Even with x as, say, 100, there won't really be a perceptible additional delay and it won't put a huge load on for processing the wait.

Comment: I think that's the issue.  I have tried multiple combinations of .Delay and all say that there is now no result.  I've also tried adding in other await statements but none seem to work, usually I end up hanging.  Even added a bunch of debug output and it's like the program just stops.

Comment: I would say, really if anything requires something to be present, that anything should be the one to generate it.  ie GetEWSClient should call and await the response from RefreshToken

Comment: I have pared down the code to a single function which seems to work although a lot more testing needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks @Hursey - I've modified my code.  I guess I was worried about calling for a new token repeatedly but I guess it doesn't matter as if there isn't one it just returns the current one and if there is it returns the new one.  So it makes sense to just keep calling it.  If you want to post that I will mark as a answer.